# Add new element to HashMap but not found when query - Kotlin

Tags: list, kotlin, hashmap

I am trying to add new list element to `HashMap` based on key value and its value is nested list.

Here is class that I initialized:

```
private val portalDummyData = listOf(
Portal(
  id = "p1", address = "Moringa", clientID = "c1", clientSecret = "cs1", agents = mutableListOf(
    Agent(
      "agent1", "agent", email, listOf(
        "p1"
      )
    ),
    Agent(
      "agent2", "agent2", email, listOf(
        "p1", "p2"
      )
    )
  )
 )
)
private val portalHashMap = HashMap<String, Portal>()

init {
  portalDummyData.forEach { portalHashMap[it.id] = it }
}
```

As you can see each value of `portalHashMap` I store as list and in that list contains another list. So, I want to add new list element to list that retains inside its parent list. But when I added new element and that element not found.

Here is code that I tried to add new list element:

```
override suspend fun addAgentToPortal(agent: Agent, id: String) {
val portal = portalHashMap[id]
if (portal != null) {
  val agents = portal.agents
  agents.toMutableList().add(agent)
  print(agents.count())
} else {
  throw NotFoundException("Portal not found")
}
}
```

I want to add new `Agent` model to that `Portal` model but when I `println(agents.count())` but the value still remains the same as default.

Comment: `agents` is already mutable list, why you are converting it again?

Comment: `toMutableList` creates a new list. So does every other `toXXX` method.

Answer (score 1):

Use mutable list instead of list. You can't add new element in List

```
Portal(
        id = "p1", address = "Moringa", clientID = "c1", clientSecret = "cs1", 
        agents = mutableListOf(
            Agent( "agent1", "agent", email, listOf("p1")),
            Agent("agent2", "agent2", email, listOf("p1", "p2"))
        )
    )
```

Comment: I have changed to `mutableListOf()` but still not work.

Comment: Have you really created mutable list of agents in your Portal or just did agents.toMutableList().add(agent)? In second case you just created mutable copy of your unmutable list which is another list.

Comment: I just created `mutableListOf` of agent in Portal

Comment: Ok. remove agents.toMutableList().add(agent) then, and add agents.add(agent)